# Progress Bar on Mac

Tags: r, macos, shiny, progress-bar

I have a question relating progress bars in R, which are shown as a pop-up window.
We are using Shiny locally on both Windows and Mac operating systems for the development phase. We would like to use the progress bar as a pop-up message because this is easier to show on Shiny. Now, in order to see the progress bar in Windows you can simply do something like:

```
pb <- winProgressBar("test progress bar", "Some information in %",
                 0, 100, 50)

u <- c(0, sort(runif(20, 0 ,100)), 100)
for(i in u) {
Sys.sleep(0.1)
info <- sprintf("%d%% done", round(i))
setWinProgressBar(pb, i, sprintf("test (%s)", info), info)
}
Sys.sleep(5)
close(pb)
```

The nice thing is that Shiny also pushes this pop-up to your screen. We want to do something similar on a Mac and these lines are not working on IOS.

Does anyone have suggestions to get this up-and-running for Mac users, i.e. other packages or ideas to get a progress bar for Mac.

Comment: I have the same issue. The `utils` package for Mac seems to be more limited compared with WIndows.

Comment: I'm unclear why you would be looking in the `utils` package for a progress bar that was implemented in `shiny`. There is a worked example on the help page for `withProgress` once the shiny package is loaded.